# Storing inbound data in memory in PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, memcached

i am building a chat app on php-mysql backend. the problem i am facing is slow mysql read writes. i have done all sorts of optimization to my queries and mysql server , the problem is actually because of hundreds of concurrent http->mysql queries from users

Now what i thought was if there was a way for php to store inbound data in memory and subsequently writing it to database via batch inserts , lets say when data reaches 100 items

Is this possible with memcached ? if yes how ? are there any other solutions for this ?

Edit : the chat app is not a web application , its for an android application

Comment: How about a 'in memory' database like SQLite?

Comment: thanks for this pointer , i was not aware of in memory databases , i will surely test it and see where it leads to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a persistant mysql connection and storing data in mysql MEMORY table. , if anyone has a better solution kindly post

Update:

I am now using apc ([Alternative PHP Cache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)) to store the inbound data (in the form of a simple array) , then putting the data in mysql with batch inserts after a number of queries

for GET requests i append the data in apc to the data fetched from mysql.